# How to generate a 1KHz singal on a PIC18F4450?

Tags: pic

I'm looking for some tips and hints to move on. The 1KHz signal should exit the microcontroller at port RD0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Failure to read the data sheet - question should be closed.

Comment: Kelvin-Herz is not a unit of anything relavent to the rest of the question.

Comment: 1) Take the code for blinking LED. I bet it's available without any effort. 2) Modify it to blink 1000 times per second. 3) Remove the LED.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As requested, here are tips and hints:

Go to http://www.microchip.com and download the datasheet.

Read it.

No, really, actually read it, particularly the sections on timers.

Read section 13 on timer 2 again, but this time notice it has its own period register.

Stop and think how this hardware might be used to create a 2 kHz periodic event, at which you can toggle a pin.  Since the pin is toggled at 2 kHz rate, its frequency will be 1 kHz.

Now read section 15 on the PWM module again.  This time think about how it can be used together with timer 1 or 3 to produce a square wave at a fixed frequency divided down from the clock.

Muse over which of these methods would fit better within your overall firmware, given what else it has to do and what hardware is available to help do it.

Write the code.